# Change filetype using zenity

Tags: command-line, bash, zenity

Having zero experience with scripting of any sort, I apologise if this question is too simple to be allowed here.

I have discovered zenity, which I think is very useful as my memory is hopeless, so if it isn't in the menu (e.g. command line apps) then I forget I have them or just forget how to use them.

So anyway.

pdftotext is an app that I have now got, and I can see me using it a fair amount in the future.
So I use a shell script calling up zenity, to be able to stick pdftotext into the menu, and hey presto it works.

I want to kid on I'm clever, so it would be nice if I could get the output text file ($szSavePath) to automatically tag ".txt" on the end.

Or even pick up the original filename ($file), strip off the .pdf and replace it with .txt as the output name.

Can either be done?

```
#!/bin/bash
file="$(zenity --title "PDF to Text:         Select a File to convert" --file-selection)"
szSavePath=$(zenity --file-selection --save --confirm-overwrite);echo $szSavePath
pdftotext "$file" $szSavePath
```

Answer (score 1):

If `file` contains `foo.pdf`, you can strip the `.pdf` using `${file%%.pdf}`.

With `szSavePath`, you can test if it contains `.txt` and add it if it doesn't:

```
szSavePath=$(zenity --file-selection --save --confirm-overwrite)
[[ $szSavePath != *.txt ]] && szSavePath="$szSavePath.txt"
```

You can provide the PDF's filename with `.txt` instead of `.pdf` as the default filename, using the `--filename` option:

```
szSavePath=$(zenity --file-selection --save --confirm-overwrite --filename="${file%%.pdf}.txt")
```

Also, remember to quote your variables, so that filenames with spaces and other special characters don't cause problems:

```
pdftotext "$file" "$szSavePath"
```